# Why C++ standard string copy is faster than string move?

Tags: c++, string, copy, move, microbenchmark

Thought string copy operation should be slower than move, but the benchmark shows it's faster.

```
static void StringCreationMove(benchmark::State & state) {
    std::string x = "hello";
    for (auto _ : state) {
        std::string created_string_move(std::move(x));
        benchmark::DoNotOptimize(created_string_move);
    }
}
BENCHMARK(StringCreationMove);

static void StringCreationCopy(benchmark::State & state) {
    std::string x = "hello";
    for (auto _ : state) {
        std::string created_string_copy(x);
        benchmark::DoNotOptimize(created_string_copy);
    }
}
BENCHMARK(StringCreationCopy);
```

If `move` doesn't allocate memory, why it's slow? Or maybe something is wrong in this benchmark it self.

UPDATE

The updated version may reflect more insights.

```
#include <benchmark/benchmark.h>

static void StringCreationMove(benchmark::State & state) {
    for (auto _ : state) {
        std::string x = "hello";
        benchmark::DoNotOptimize(x);
        std::string created_string_move(std::move(x));
        benchmark::DoNotOptimize(created_string_move);
    }
}
BENCHMARK(StringCreationMove);

static void StringCreationCopy(benchmark::State & state) {
    for (auto _ : state) {
        std::string x = "hello";
        benchmark::DoNotOptimize(x);
        std::string created_string_copy(x);
        benchmark::DoNotOptimize(created_string_copy);
    }
}
BENCHMARK(StringCreationCopy);

BENCHMARK_MAIN();
```

Result on my MacBook Air 2013.

```
Run on (4 X 1300 MHz CPU s)
CPU Caches:
  L1 Data 32 KiB (x2)
  L1 Instruction 32 KiB (x2)
  L2 Unified 256 KiB (x2)
  L3 Unified 3072 KiB (x1)
Load Average: 1.51, 1.49, 1.74
-------------------------------------------------------------
Benchmark                   Time             CPU   Iterations
-------------------------------------------------------------
StringCreationMove       72.0 ns         67.6 ns     11394713
StringCreationCopy       47.1 ns         47.1 ns     14960781
```

Comment: The first time the original string gets moved away it's left in "some valid but unspecified state". Therefore, on the 2nd iteration of the loop you're not really moving the original string. This could trigger some sub-optimal runtime behavior. In the case of copy-construction if the underlying `std::string` implementation uses reference-counting the whole thing becomes just incrementing/decrementing a counter. In the move case some actual allocation/deallocation can take place. Can't really say anything authoritative without examining the resulting code for this.

Comment: "Therefore, on the 2nd iteration of the loop you're not really moving the original string. This could trigger some sub-optimal runtime behavior." >> This should be the case. Others are also valuable.Thanks @SamVarshavchik.

Answer (score 1):

The benchmark results are different if you use the standard libstd++ (GNU) or libc++ (llvm). The last gives the moving is faster: https://quick-bench.com/q/DV-lRSuipynW2QilZZvCV91uWHY
[image: "hello" + LLVM standard C++ library]

As for the answer to your question. The string "hello" is too short and the small string optimization is applied. It means a small array is used for small strings, so there is no advantage of the moving. It depends on the implementation, but probably GNU std::string does not optimally copy the array's data when moving performed. If you use long enough strings, the moving is always faster.

GNU: https://quick-bench.com/q/QFlfvUJ_Rua6g95koevFZsNaLrg
[image: "Hello morning World! Merry Christmas!" + GNU standard C++ library]
LLVM: https://quick-bench.com/q/iJgfzrWc3yNUMkBYnbPI02e1lW4
[image: "Hello morning World! Merry Christmas!" + LLVM standard C++ library]

Comment: Summary of you points: 1. library matters (GNU vs LLVM); 2. string size matters, move will beat copy if strings are longer; Thanks!